# Why is hidden-city ticketing possible?

Tags: hidden-city-ticketing

I have read in various posts why hidden-city-ticketing is a bad thing for the passengers and for the airplane-company (for example [here](https://www.skyscanner.com/tips-and-inspiration/hidden-city-ticketing) or  [here](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/hobica/2015/01/06/skiplagged-hidden-city-ticketing/21290655/))

However, I still did not grasp, how come that a flight from **A to B to C**, is cheaper then a flight from just **A to B**?

Comment: I heard in the news, a while ago, that Schiphol, Amsterdam airport, got permission for a given number of flights as long as a given percentage of the passengers were transfer passengers. I can not find it on internet now, but it would give a reason for airlines to lower the prices for transfer passengers. (But I still think it is insane to get a price reduction for adding more miles and more starts and stops.)

Comment: you think of it as a price reduction because you think there is one price. But there are many prices, and when you  know that it makes more sense.

Comment: Airlines discourage hidden city ticketing since it prevents them from price gauging non-stop flights. Hidden city is actually great for passengers since it allows to work around some fairly questionable pricing policies. Lufthansa and United have sued to enforce this, but so far the courts have sided with the passengers.

Comment: There's nothing nefarious about it and it's perfectly legal.  There is simply more demand A->B then A->C.  Demand drives prices.  That A->C is actually A->B->C is incidental, meaning it doesn't matter to the airline mearly as much as people think it should.  Same as buying a Happy Meal just for the toy.